# expandablelistview checkboxes not staying checked

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

I am using a local sqlite db that is saving everything properly.  When I open up a group in the expandableListView, all the checkboxes that have been stored in the db the check box is checked.  When I edit an entry(I used an AlertDialog), close the group and then reopen the group.  The checkbox is no longer checked.  I checked the db and the edit was saved.  If I go to another page and come back, once I click on the group, the child item I edited is once again checked.  I used breakpoints in eclipse and it seems to find the data in the db, but not mark the box as checked.  Any ideas?

[image]

This is the image of when I first click on the group(Engine)

[image]

Now I am using an AlertDialog to update the entry

[image]

Now I close the group

[image]

When I reopen the box by Battery is no longer checked.

Here is the code for when I open a group

```
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition)
{
    db= new InspectionRecordsTableDBAdapter(getBaseContext());
    db.open();
    int inspectionId = com.signalsetapp.inspectionchecklist.report
            .returnStringID();
    String [] child=kids[groupPosition];
    ArrayList<Color> secList = new ArrayList<Color>();
    for(int i=0; i<child.length;i++)
    {
        try {
            if (db.childFound(inspectionId, child[i]))
                secList.add(new Color(child[i], true));
            else
                secList.add(new Color(child[i], false));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            secList.add(new Color(child[i], false));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

}

and here is the update code the save into the db. This does save properly into the db

```
db.editRecords(
                                        primaryId,
                                        com.signalsetapp.inspectionchecklist.report
                                                .returnStringID(),
                                        parent[groupPosition],
                                        kids[groupPosition][childPosition],
                                        input.getText().toString(), status);
                                onExpand=true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `requery()` your group cursor after you save to the database and it should regenerate the list views ( or the asynchronous equivalent since requery has been deprecated).